# format a specific line in a QtextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt4

How do you go about selecting a specific line in a QTextEdit and changing say... The font colour to green

I am using a QTextEdit widget to display the content of a file, a sequence of commands being sent over rs232. I would like to provide some visual feedback as to what line is being executed, say change the text colour.

I am able to change the text file of text being appended to a QTextEdit (for a log I display) but that doesn't work.

I have been looking into Qcursors but am a bit lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using cursors:

```
    self.script_cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.scriptBuffer.document())
    self.scriptBuffer.setTextCursor(self.script_cursor)
    self.script_cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.Start)
    for i in range(data):
        self.script_cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.Down)

    self.script_cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.EndOfLine)
    self.script_cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.Start, QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
    tmp = self.script_cursor.blockFormat()
    tmp.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.yellow))
    self.script_cursor.setBlockFormat(tmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can afford generating a new TextEdit content from the relevant data, every time something changes. That should be very easy to implement. `QCursor`s and stuff like that is good for editable `QTextEdit`s which is not true in your case. And there is no guarantee that it will be faster at all.

Comment: Yup the same thing is happening to me good idea.If you are listening

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the QTextDocument.findBlockByLineNumber(). When you have the block you can simply search for "\n" and use the QTextBlock.firstLineNumber() to see where the line starts and ends. Then you can change the block QTextBlock.charFormat().

```
def edit_line(editor, line_number):
    """Use the text cursor to select the given line number and change the formatting.

    ..note:: line number offsets may be incorrect

    Args:
        editor (QTextBrowser): QTextBrowser you want to edit
        line_num (int): Line number  you want to edit.
    """
    linenum = line_number - 1 
    block = editor.document().findBlockByLineNumber(linenum)
    diff = linenum - block.firstLineNumber()
    count = 0
    if diff == 0:
        line_len = len(block.text().split("\n")[0])
    else:
        # Probably don't need. Just in case a block has more than 1 line.
        line_len = 0
        for i, item in enumerate(block.text().split("\n")):
            # Find start
            if i + 1 == diff: # + for line offset. split starts 0
                count += 2 # \n
                line_len = len(item)
            else:
                count += len(item)

    loc = block.position() + count

    # Set the cursor to select the text
    cursor = editor.textCursor()

    cursor.setPosition(loc)
    cursor.movePosition(cursor.Right, cursor.KeepAnchor, line_len)

    charf = block.charFormat()
    charf.setFontUnderline(True) # Change formatting here
    cursor.setCharFormat(charf)
    # cursor.movePosition(cursor.Right, cursor.MoveAnchor, 1)
    # editor.setTextCursor(cursor)
# end edit_line
```

example:

```
editor = QtGui.QTextEdit()
editor.setText("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n")

line_num = 6
edit_line(editor, line_num)
```

Or a simple way would be to grab all of the text search for the line from "\n". The wrap that line in html/css tags and reset the text. With this approach you would have to change everything to html and make sure the formatting is right (editor.toHtml()).